# How to save ordered multiple upload files in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a Django form to upload multiple images with.

With Javascript, I allow user to see files name and sort it using sortable.min.js library before submitting the form but its only a UI feature.

Is it possible to save the files using the order the user gives?

```
last_position = property.images.last().position

for index, item in enumerate(self.request.FILES.getlist('image'), start=last_position + 1):
    i = Image(prop=property, image=item, position=index)
    i.save()
```

Comment: Have you checked if the code you posted works? If not, which error/behavior do you observe?

Comment: Yes the code works, but Django sends files into a dictionary and I need to order this files to save in the database with a position field.